# Fetch request in class component is not returning data or updating state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

I have refactored a component to add a `fetch` request to an `AWS` database, the data is accessible and a quick mock on `codesandbox` works. However when used in this context it errors as...

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined
>   Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): this.setState is not a function

and in the console...

```
{error: null, isLoaded: true, users: Array(0), undefined}
```

code below...

```
  constructor() {
    this.mapUserCountries = {};
    this.state = {
      error: null,
      isLoaded: true,
      users: []
    };
  }

  init() {
    this.getUsers = () => {
      fetch(
        "DATABASE"
      )
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(
          result => {
            this.setState({
              isLoaded: true,
              users: result.users
            });
            console.log(result, this.state);
          },
          error => {
            this.setState({
              isLoaded: true,
              error
            });
          }
        );
    };

    const mappedUsers = this.getUsers();

    console.log(this.state, mappedUsers);

    mappedUsers.forEach(user => {
      const c = user.country;

      if (!this.mapUserCountries[c])
        this.mapUserCountries[c] = { nbUsers: 0, users: [] };
      this.mapUserCountries[c].nbUsers++;
      this.mapUserCountries[c].users.push(user);
    });
  }

  getUsersPerCountry(country) {
    return this.mapUserCountries[country];
  }
}

export default new UsersManager();
```

Comment: could you share the codesandbox?

Answer (score 1):

```
async init() {
  ...
  const mappedUsers = await this.getUsers();
  ...
```

You're in async land now.

Answer (score 0):

There is no defined setState function on the UsersManager class, you will need to create that function

Comment: thanks! I've added in the above edits, which is great however I'm still getting this.setstate is not a function. When you say create it within my usermanagers class, can i simply add it here? constructor() {
    this.mapUserCountries = {};
    this.setState = {};
    this.state = {
      error: null,
      isLoaded: true,
      users: []
    };
  }

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to return promise in order to `await` it

```js
this.getUsers = () => {
      return fetch(
        "DATABASE"
      )
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(
          result => {
            this.setState({
              isLoaded: true,
              users: result.users
            });
            console.log(result, this.state);
          },
          error => {
            this.setState({
              isLoaded: true,
              error
            });
          }
        );
    };
```

or use implicit return `() => fetch(...)`

then,

```js
async init() {
  ...
  const mappedUsers = await this.getUsers();
}
// or
init() {
  ...
  this.getUsers().then((mappedUsers) => { ... });
}
```