# How to call a react hook fetch request in a functional component to access data then pass to a class component to map?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, fetch, react-hooks

After a huge amount of trial and error for a complex webGL project I have landed on a solution that will reduce the amount of re-engineering working, threejs code (from another developer) and, as this project is extremely time restrained, reduce the amount of time needed. It's also worth noting my experience of this is limited and I am the only developer left on the team.

The project current accepts a large array of random user data, which is exported from a js file and then consumed here...

```
import Users from "./data/data-users";

class UsersManager {
  constructor() {
    this.mapUserCountries = {};
  }

  init() {
    Users.forEach(user => {
      const c = user.country;

      if (!this.mapUserCountries[c])
        this.mapUserCountries[c] = { nbUsers: 0, users: [] };
      this.mapUserCountries[c].nbUsers++;
      this.mapUserCountries[c].users.push(user);
    });
  }

  getUsersPerCountry(country) {
    return this.mapUserCountries[country];
  }
}

export default new UsersManager();
```

Here is my fetch request..

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const FetchUsers = () => {
  const [hasError, setErrors] = useState(false);
  const [users, setUsers] = useState({});

  async function fetchData() {
    const res = await fetch(
      "https://swapi.co/api/planets/4/"
    );
    res
      .json()
      .then(res => setUsers(res))
      .catch(err => setErrors(err));
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return JSON.stringify(users);
};

export default FetchUsers;
```

I have run into lots of issues as the UserManager is a class component and if I import my fetchUsers into this file, call it and save it to a variable like so const Users = fetchUsers(); it violates hooks.

I want to be able to return a function that will return my users from the database as an array.

That will then be able to be passed into the UserManager in the same way the hard coded data is and mapped over to be actioned by LOTS of other files.

I've mocked up a small codesandbox with what the flow would be ideally but I know I need a solution outside of hooks...

https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-borg-u2yl6

thanks

--- EDIT ---

```
import usersP from "./data/data-users";

class UsersManager {
  constructor() {
    this.mapUserCountries = {};
    this.state = {
      users: undefined
    };
  }

  init() {
    usersP.then(users => {
      this.setState({ users });
    });
    console.log(usersP);
    this.state.users.forEach(user => {
      const c = user.country;
      if (!this.mapUserCountries[c])
        this.mapUserCountries[c] = { nbUsers: 0, users: [] };
      this.mapUserCountries[c].nbUsers++;
      this.mapUserCountries[c].users.push(user);
    });
  }

  getUsersPerCountry(country) {
    return this.mapUserCountries[country];
  }
}

export default new UsersManager();
```

```
console.log (UsersManager.js:16 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined
    at UsersManager.init (UsersManager.js:16)
    at Loader.SceneApp.onLoadingComplete [as callback] (App.js:39)
    at Loader.onAssetLoaded (index.js:20)
    at index.js:36
    at three.module.js:36226
    at HTMLImageElement.onImageLoad)
```

Comment: I don't really understand what you are trying to do, in your example you are using hooks outside of a component, that's why you have an error. If you want to make an http request outside of a component, just call it without using react hooks

Comment: Hey @OlivierBoissé I have tried this also but I only want to return the data rather than a component that renders the data https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60380841/fetch-request-in-class-component-is-not-returning-data-or-updating-state

Comment: I also did not understand what you want to do, if you need an array of object, just import it, vanilla javascript way, if you need it to be in an FC, pass it as a prop, ...
Assuming that you need the stringified version of what is fetched, this is a small fix to your code. https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-hodgkin-uj004

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed your [sandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-shadow-idq5r).

You cannot load the users synchronously (using `import`) as you need to make a http call to fetch the users so it's **asynchronous**.

As a result you can fetch the users inside the `componentDidMount` lifecycle method and use a state variable to store them once they are fetched

Comment: Thanks so much @olivier - I've tried to implement that as a solution in the code as that makes sense! However as the UserManager is a constructor class rather than a class that returns any JSX it was created and is called on init(). So in the main App.js file it's called as UserManagers.init(). Can you think of a way around this? I've edited the UsersManager file with your amends so you can see what I mean

Comment: you cannot use `this.setState` outside of a React class component. If you want to retrieve the users in `UserManagement`, you need to return a promise and then you can use it inside you App component and store the users in a state variable using `this.setState`

Comment: Ok that would explain why i'm getting so many errors. So both the usersmanager.js and the app.js are set up as `export default class SceneApp` then use `init()` . I'd assumed that these are the same as react class components?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple guidelines that will help separate functions that are Hooks and functions that are Components (these are true most of the time):

1 Component functions use pascal case (start with a capital letter) and always return JSX.

2 Custom Hooks functions conventionally begin with the word "use" and never return JSX.

In your case you probably want to make a custom Hooks function that must be called in a component;

```
function useUserData() {
  const [hasError, setErrors] = useState(false);
  const [users, setUsers] = useState({});

  const networkCall = useCallback(async fetchData = () => {
    const res = await fetch(
      "https://swapi.co/api/planets/4/"
    );
    res
      .json()
      .then(res => setUsers(res))
      .catch(err => setErrors(err));
  } , [])

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return {users, hasError};
}
```

Then call that custom hook in one of your components:

```
function App() {
  const {users, hasError} = useUserData();

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
        <div>{users}</div>
        <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

If you then need to share that fetched data throughout your app, you can pass it down via props or the context API: https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html
(post a message if you'd like an example of this).